How do I print all exact unique values from a dataframe in sorted order?
I am trying to see all exact values in a dataframe sorted by numeric value. To my surprise the 'unique' command does not show all unique values. My thought was that maybe there was a subcommand to unique or something, but I could not find anything. This code illustrates what I tried to do and the output I expected.
d <- data.frame(
  crp = as.numeric(c("1.0001","1","0.999999999", "0.999999999")),
  crp.txt = as.integer(c("1.0001","1","0.999999999", "0.999999999")) 
)

sort(unique(d$crp)) # is sorted but doesn't show exact values
sort(unique(toString(d$crp))) # is not sorted but shows all values

sort(unique(d$crp.txt)) # is sorted but doesn't show exact values
sort(unique(toString(d$crp.txt))) # is not sorted and doesn't show exact values
 
# expected output: [1] "0.999999999, 1, 1.0001"


Am I doing something wrong / should I do it differently?

Does d exactly mimic the data structure and types of your real data? Why is treating all columns as one appropriate?

The issue was of a more general kind, not for just a few specific variables. I put the same values to compare.

I think the issue is that when you convert the column to a string using toString(), you're converting the entire column into a single string, which is not what you want. Instead, you should convert each element of the column to a string individually using as.character(). Here there is an alternative:
sort(unique(unlist(d)))

[1] "0.999999999" "1"           "1.0001" 

Also, if you want to use your code, you can do the following:
# Convert each element of d$crp to character and then get unique values
unique(as.character(d$crp))
# Sort the unique values
sort(unique_crp)


# Convert each element of d$crp.txt to character and then get unique values
unique(as.character(d$crp.txt))
# Sort the unique values
sort(unique_crp_txt)

